# Django inserts new object after save() method instead of update

Tags: python, django, django-models

When trying to ***update*** an existing Django model object (with the `save()` method), a ***new*** row is inserted instead.

---

For example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from data_lib.models import Meal
>>> m = Meal(name="My First Meal!", description="this is my first meal's description")
>>> print m.mealid
None
>>> m.save()
>>> print m.mealid
None
>>> m.save()
```

after that second `save()` method call, a duplicate entry was inserted into my table.

---

here is a sample of the model definition:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    mealid = models.IntegerField(db_column='MealId', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=45, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Django docs ([1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#field-options), [2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#primary-key)):

> The primary key field is read-only. If you change the value of the primary key on an existing object and then save it, a new object will be created alongside the old one.

---

The issue was in the model object's class definition.

Once I set the primary_key field to an `AutoField`, the issue went away.
My new model definition is as follows:

---

```
class Meal(models.Model):
        mealid = models.AutoField(db_column='MealId', primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=45, blank=True)
        description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', max_length=200, blank=True)
```

---

An almost perfect auto-generation by Django!