# Django tries to INSERT instead of UPDATE on save()

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model

```
class DeviceAdmin(models.Model):
    dev_id = models.AutoField(db_column='dev_id', primary_key=True)
...
```

A view locates an object:

```
device = DeviceAdmin.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
```

then it makes some changes (or maybe not)

```
if (...):
    device.os_type = 'windows'
...
```

then it tries to save any changes:

```
device.save()
```

Here's where Django attempts to insert anther row instead of updating, causing a DB error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

There's a kind of similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084697/django-inserts-new-object-after-save-method-instead-of-update) with solution:

> Once I set the primary_key field to an AutoField, the issue went away.

However, my primary key is already an AutoField.

So I stepped through django code with debugger, and fund this in file `...site-packages\django\models\base.py`:

```
    # If possible, try an UPDATE. If that doesn't update anything, do an INSERT.
    if pk_set and not force_insert:
        base_qs = cls._base_manager.using(using)
        values = [(f, None, (getattr(self, f.attname) if raw else f.pre_save(self, False)))
                  for f in non_pks]
        forced_update = update_fields or force_update
        updated = self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields,
                                  forced_update)
        if force_update and not updated:
            raise DatabaseError("Forced update did not affect any rows.")
        if update_fields and not updated:
            raise DatabaseError("Save with update_fields did not affect any rows.")
    if not updated:
        if meta.order_with_respect_to:
            # If this is a model with an order_with_respect_to
            # autopopulate the _order field
            field = meta.order_with_respect_to
            filter_args = field.get_filter_kwargs_for_object(self)
            order_value = cls._base_manager.using(using).filter(**filter_args).count()
            self._order = order_value

        fields = meta.local_concrete_fields
        if not pk_set:
            fields = [f for f in fields if f is not meta.auto_field]

        update_pk = meta.auto_field and not pk_set
        result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
        if update_pk:
            setattr(self, meta.pk.attname, result)
    return updated
```

It seems that if there are no changes (and thus update doesn't do anything), then it will try to insert a duplicate record.

I tested this with adding a save right after `get`:

```
device = DeviceAdmin.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
device.save()
```

and it's trying to insert a duplicate.

Does this mean, my code needs to keep track if an object has to be saved to DB or not?

What's the simplest way to get around this problem?

---

UPDATE:

As a test, I put a `save` immediately after finding an object with `get`, without any changes:

```
device = DeviceAdmin.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
device.save()
```

Django should know that the object is an existing one. And yet, it tries to insert a duplicate.

Similarly, creating a new object and calling `save` twice:

```
device = DeviceAdmin(...) # create a new object (it has null `dev_id`)
device.save()             # insert the new object into DB; get 'dev_id'
                          #   for the newly inserted record
device.save()             # This shouldn't do anything!
```

This second `save` attempts to insert a duplicate - as I can see if I step through the django code with debugger.

Comment: Are your sequences messed up at all? [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11089850/1324033)

Comment: Have you try this way (although I'm not sure if it'd fix): `device.save(update_fields=['field'])` or instead you could use `device = DeviceAdmin.objects.filter(uuid=uuid).update(field=value)`

Comment: Sequences are fine. I checked.

Comment: Your diagnosis is incorrect. The `updated` flag would only be False if no rows were matched, ie the PK does not exist. It wouldn't be False if the PK existed but the values were set to the same as they are now.

Comment: I don't have a diagnosis. I'm only describing the symptoms. `updated` appeared to be `False` in debugger

Comment: From your other question I know that you already have tables in the db. Can you show what happens if you use code generated by `manage.py inspectdb` for your model? And you can always fall-back to using `.save(force_update=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have some issues with fields definition (maybe for some reason you should add `unique=True`). But if you still can't determine why UPDATE fails (`INSERT` happens if `UPDATE` returns "no rows updated"), then you can use `.save(force_update=True)` as a last resort.

Also you have some inconsistency in your code:

- field is named as `dev_id` but you are using `uuid` in filtering (`.get(uuid=uuid)`). Are you sure that you have properly set a name for primary_key field?
- `AutoField` is assuming the use of `Integer` field, so during `get_prep_value` it does `int(self.pk)` which works without throwing any errors on instances of `uuid.UUID`, But if internally db uses `varchar` field, then it will be converted back to str with a wrong value (e.g. `str(int(uuid.UUID('579aea21-49a4-4819-90ec-a192014b4a44'))) == '116447198070669671892400511866020514372'`). So that's what might be causing the problems. Instead of AutoField try using `UUIDField` or `CharField`:

```py
import uuid


class SomeModel(models.Model): 

    dev_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, blank=True, default=uuid.uuid4)

# Or if your column is a varchar:

class SomeModel(models.Model): 

    def dev_id_default():
        return uuid.uuid4().hex  # or str(uuid.uuid4()) if you need values with `-`

    dev_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, blank=True, default=dev_id_default, max_length=33_OR_36)
```

Looks like you are using pre-existing tables in DB: try using code for models generated by [`python manage.py inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models).

Comment: for .save(force_update=True), if the DB returns the no change, will it still override it or it will not take any action behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a unique CharField at the top of my class. It seemed to me that Django would sometimes see it as the primary key, sometimes not -- with the consequence of sometimes not realizing it should be updating instead of inserting.

Adding an explicit `id=AutoField(primary_key=True)` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why this might occur is if your primary key field is defined with a default value. I don't see a default in your example, but I also don't see that the datatype is a uuid, so I thought I would provide this answer just in case.

If your model's pkey looks like this: `models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)`, calling `save` will always result in an INSERT rather than an UPDATE. I believe this is true even if you pass `force_update=True` to the save method. This was at one point submitted as a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33052), but
is actually the intended behavior of Django 3 [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.0/#model-save-when-providing-a-default-for-the-primary-key).

There are a couple of ways you can handle this issue if you want to use a uuid as your primary key. The best way is probably to follow the recommendation of the docs and use either the update or update_or_create methods to update your model instances.

```
>>> MyModel.objects.update_or_create(pk=existing_pk, defaults={'name': 'new name'})
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(pk=existing_pk).update(name='new name')
```

Alternatively, you could also remove the default argument from your primary key definition and ensure that each instance has a uuid assigned on save by overriding your model's save method - for example:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.id = uuid.uuid1()
        super(DeviceAdmin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```